# Hexagon grid with border and image responsive (clip path probably)

Tags: css, clip-path

I already asked a similar question but it seems my code is not correct.

I used border in pixels and it is not responsive. I used bootsrtrap to make it responsive but then the hexagons are not as a grid (everyone next to the other)

Here is an image what should be done.

[image]

This is how it looks now

[image]

Here is my code, which probably is not the right one to allow me to achieve the image above. My hexagons are not as a grid (close to each others), are not scalable and are not responsive.

```css
.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px; 
  height: 115.47px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 57.74px 0;
  border-left: solid 2px #4850be;
  border-right: solid 2px #4850be;
}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 141.42px;
  height: 141.42px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: inherit;
  left: 27.2893px;
  z-index:1;
}

.hexagon:before {
  top: -70.7107px;
  border-top: solid 2.8284px #4850be;
  border-right: solid 2.8284px #4850be;
}

.hexagon:after {
  bottom: -70.7107px;
  border-bottom: solid 2.8284px #4850be;
  border-left: solid 2.8284px #4850be;
}

/* NEW */
.icon-box{
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4850be;
  position: absolute;
  top:-35px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 10;
}

.icon-box:before,
.icon-box:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: inherit;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #4850be;
  z-index:1;
}

.icon-box:before {
  top: -25px;
}

.icon-box:after {
  bottom: -25px;
}

.icon-box i,
.icon-box img
 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 20;
  font-size: 80px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.text {
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.text h3 {
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<section id="content">
                <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3 col-6-medium col-12-small">
                            <div class="hexagon">
                                <div class="icon-box"><img src="images/section/section_2_icon_man.png" alt="" ></div>
                                <div class="text">
                                    <h3>Head of Trust & Safety,Video Streaming Platform</h3>
                                    <p>"ActiveFence is the foundation of our proactive moderation efforts. It's easy to show that there is no in-house equivalent we could ever develop. Even the best internal teams will never have ActiveFence's subject matter and linguistic expertise, and the cross platform visibility their technology provides is invaluable to keeping our users safe." </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3 col-6-medium col-12-small">
                            <div class="hexagon">
                            <div class="icon-box"><img src="images/section/section_2_icon_woman.png" alt="" ></div>
                                <div class="text">
                                    <h3>Head of Trust & Safety,Video Streaming Platform</h3>
                                    <p>"ActiveFence is the foundation of our proactive moderation efforts. It's easy to show that there is no in-house equivalent we could ever develop. Even the best internal teams will never have ActiveFence's subject matter and linguistic expertise, and the cross platform visibility their technology provides is invaluable to keeping our users safe." </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3 col-6-medium col-12-small">
                            <div class="hexagon">
                            <div class="icon-box"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                                <div class="text">
                                    <h3>Head of Trust & Safety,Video Streaming Platform</h3>
                                    <p>"ActiveFence is the foundation of our proactive moderation efforts. It's easy to show that there is no in-house equivalent we could ever develop. Even the best internal teams will never have ActiveFence's subject matter and linguistic expertise, and the cross platform visibility their technology provides is invaluable to keeping our users safe." </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your webpage/website is not responsive because you used `px`, to make it responsive use **Viewport Units** like `vw` for **width** and `vh` for **height** instead of `px` and `%` to make your webpage/website responsive. ***(Note:- 1vw=0.5cm)***

It will surely work but if it doesn't let me know in the comments, I will try my best to help you.

Comment: Thank you. The webpage is responsive.The first my problem is that the hexagons are not next to each other (they are in bootstrap grid and as such they are responsive). If I remove the bootstrap grid I need the hexagons to be next to each other and to resize and become vertical when the page resizes. I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: I added how my hexagons work now. The gap should be removed and in mobile view the hexagons should be below each other in a column. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Jenny I am really sorry I don't have any idea about that but can you do me a favour  that as soon as you resolve this issue please let me know I would love to know how you did it.

Comment: @Jenny I wanted to know whether your issue was solved or not I am eagerly waiting to know how you solved it.

Comment: No, my issue hasn't been resolved yet. I still need help.

Comment: @Jenny Sad to hear that your issue is not solved but please let me know as soon as you  resolve it.

Comment: I removed the padding using unordered list (every li is a hexagon) with ul dipaly:flex;

Comment: @Jenny I am so happy to hear that your issue is solved and thanks for saying how you solved it. And can you do me a favour that if I was able to help you even a bit please accept and upvote my answer, it would meana a lot to me. And once again thanks for teaching me something new.

Comment: @Jenny Thanks for upvoting my answer but can you please also accept it because it would make my day, it's ok if you don't want to do it but I am tryna grow on stack overflow and it would really help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort it out. Here is my different way:

```css
#content-middle {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 100vh;
            margin: 0 auto;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        
        #content-middle::before {
            top: 0;
            height: 100%;
            background: #f4f4f6;
            -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 46%, 0% 100%, 54% 100%);
            clip-path: polygon(0 46%, 0% 100%, 54% 100%);
            z-index: -1;
        }
        
        #content-middle::before, #content::after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
 
        .hexWrapper {
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0px;
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 150px; /*Change this to resize*/
            height: 150px; /*Change this to resize*/
            min-width: 150px;
            min-height: 150px;
            float:left;
        }           
    
        .hexagon {
            height: calc(100%/1.732050807);
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            display:inline-block;
        }

        .hexagon:before,
        .hexagon:after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            background-color: inherit;
            height: inherit;
            width: inherit;
            left: -1px; right: -1px; top: 0; bottom: 0;
        }

        .hexagon:before {
            transform: rotateZ(60deg);
        }

        .hexagon:after {
            transform: rotateZ(120deg);
        }

        .hexagon,
        .hexagon:before,
        .hexagon:after {
            box-sizing: content-box;
            border: solid 2px #4850be;
            border-top-width: 0;
            border-bottom-width: 0;
            z-index: -1; /*We need to force the z-index so we can put some text over*/
        }

        #container{
            padding-top: 60px;
            width:100%;
            min-width:910px; /* so the page doesn't get too small. This should be done better with media queries*/
        }

        .row-hexagon{
            clear:both; /*to reset all the configs*/
            float:left;
            display: flex; /* using some flex to aline to center */
            justify-content: center;
            overflow:hidden; /*this is for after, when we add more hex's*/
            padding-top:145px; /* To take care of the top part of the hex, needs changing if we change the size on the wrapper*/
            position:relative; 
        }

        .fullWidth{
            width: 100%;
        }
 
 
        .icon-box{
            width: 75px;
            height:40px;
            background-color: #4850be;
            position: absolute;
            top:-25px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin: auto;
            z-index: 10;
        }

        .icon-box:before,
        .icon-box:after{
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
            -ms-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
            transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
            background-color: inherit;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin: auto;
            background-color: #4850be;
            z-index:1;
        }

        .icon-box:before {
            top: -25px;
        }

        .icon-box:after {
            bottom: -25px;
        }

        .icon-box i,
        .icon-box img {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: -20px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            z-index: 20;
            font-size: 90px;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .text {
            z-index: 10;
            position: relative;
            font-size: 17px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .text h3 {
            font-size: 1em;
            color:#42c9c0;
            font-weight:700;
        }
        
        .text h4{
            font-size: 0.8em;
            color:#42c9c0;
            font-weight:300;
        }
        
        .text p{
            font-size: 0.5em;
            font-weight:300;
            font-style:italic;
        }
```

```html
<!-- <!-- FonT Awesome for demo purposes here --> -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<section id="content-middle">
                
                    <div id="container-hexagon">
                        <div class="row-hexagon fullWidth" id="firstRow">
                            <div class="hexWrapper">
                                <div class="hexagon">
                                    <div class="icon-box"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                                    <div class="text">
                                    <h3>Title</h3>
                                    <h4>Subtitle </h4>
                                    <p>Text</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="hexWrapper">
                                <div class="hexagon">
                                    <div class="icon-box"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                                    <div class="text">
                                    <h3>Title</h3>
                                    <h4>Subtitle </h4>
                                    <p>Text</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="hexWrapper">
                                <div class="hexagon">
                                    <div class="icon-box"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                                    <div class="text">
                                    <h3>Title</h3>
                                    <h4>Subtitle </h4>
                                    <p>Text</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```